# Pytorch lightning Datamodule override warning: Signature of method '.setup()' does not match signature of base method in class 'LightningDataModule'

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

The following is a working Pytorch Lightning DataModule.

```
import os
from pytorch_lightning import LightningDataModule
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torchvision.transforms import transforms
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from Testing.Research.config.paths import mnist_data_download_folder


class PressureDataModule(LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, config):        
        super().__init__()
        self._config = config

    def prepare_data(self):
        pass

    def setup(self, stage):
        # transform
        transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
        mnist_train_full = datasets.MNIST(mnist_data_download_folder, train=True, download=False, transform=self._transforms)
        mnist_test = datasets.MNIST(mnist_data_download_folder, train=False, download=False, transform=self._transforms)

        # train/val split
        train_size = int(self._config.train_size /
                         (self._config.train_size + self._config.val_size) * len(mnist_train_full))
        val_size = len(mnist_train_full) - train_size
        mnist_train, mnist_val = torch.utils.data.random_split(mnist_train_full, [train_size, val_size])

        # assign to use in dataloaders
        self._train_dataset = mnist_train
        self._val_dataset = mnist_val
        self._test_dataset = mnist_test

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self._train_dataset, batch_size=self._config.batch_size, num_workers=self._config.num_workers)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self._val_dataset, batch_size=self._config.batch_size, num_workers=self._config.num_workers)

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self._test_dataset, batch_size=self._config.batch_size, num_workers=self._config.num_workers)
```

Pycharm doesn't like `setup` with

> Signature of method 'PressureDataModule.setup()' does not match
> signature of base method in class 'LightningDataModule'

1. If there is no match, why is Pycharm crying?
2. Is it because of different parameters? What is the correct number of parameters?

What's the correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that simple copy-paste the parent method signature solves this issue:

```py
def setup(self, stage: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
    ...
```